# Selecting penalty weight term in regularized negative binomial regression

Tags: r, regression, python, regularization, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm looking to run regularized negative binomial regression over my data. I'm currently working in R using glmregNB (page 34 [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mpath/mpath.pdf)) and am able to fit a model, but I'm not quite sure how to interpret the output. The model tries 100 different values for lambda (the penalty weight term, if I'm not mistaken), but how should I go about selecting the "best" one?

I've thought about comparing the AIC or log-likelihood values for each selected lambda, but it seems that those measures are not informative in my case since the lowest AIC value will correspond with no penalty term.

I've implemented the same model in python with [`statsmodels.formula.api.negativebinomial`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.formula.api.negativebinomial.html) and used the `fit_regularized()`, but as far as I can tell, this involves selecting a penalty term ahead of time. Using python would be preferable to me since statsmodels gives p-values for the regression coefficients, and the R model I'm using does not.

**Essentially, how do you decide the penalty weight term of a regularized negative binomial regression in R or Python**?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unless your data are spatial or temporal, a nice general-purpose way to choose penalties is via the title of this website :)

Comment: Thank you! I actually forgot to mention that I did try cross validation (in Python) and the penalty weight term that got the best prediction accuracy was > 4000, which seems suspicious to me. I also am not intending to use my model for prediction, so I wasn't sure that "prediction accuracy" was necessarily a logical metric to use to select the best model. Some collaborators suspect that the packages themselves may have some way to select the best parameter, but I've yet to find it

Comment: Can you help us understand why 4,000 is suspicious?

Comment: I guess I don’t have a precise reason, other (more experienced) collaborators hadn't seen such a high term before, and I have mostly seen examples using small penalty terms, so I wanted to double check if I was missing some more accurate/common way to select the penalty term

Comment: Without know more about exactly how the library you're using parameterizes things, we in general can't expect this number to be in any particular range, because reasonable values are going to vary as a function of: 1) your likelihood 2) your error variance 3) your sample size. Depending on how things are parameterized, the optimizing $\lambda$ can go to $\infty$ as the data size increases. Certain libraries on the other hand, like sklearn's logistic regression, normalizes by $n$ (in which case we don't necessarily expect divergence of $\lambda$).

Comment: related: AIC and similar require effective degrees of freedom or effective number of parameters which is not implemented in statsmodels discrete fit_regularized, AFAICS. (Only GAM has effective degrees of freedom in statsmodels, AFAIR) e.g. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5311